# Help! How to draw the plot of y=(ax+b)/(cx+d) and give an example!

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, plot, pst-plot

I find in pst-plot.pdf, pst-func.pdf document but there is no its tutorial. So I hope anyone help me to draw the plot of it.(its code :-)) ). Thanks.

Example: 
y=(x-2)/(2x+1)

[image]

Can anyone draw it by Pstricks environment?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Note this is a Q&A site, not a please do this for me service. What do you have so far.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know its code so i hope anyone know about it to help me.

Comment: Vietnamese TikZ tutorial: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k4Q6xszgqNFPhc5aWQ9iJatBXG-diLAO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: There is no the plot of functions y=(ax+b)/(cx+d). :))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgfplots}



\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle]
\addplot[smooth,domain=-4:-8/11,purple,very thick] {(x-2)/(2*x+1)};
\addplot[smooth,domain=-2/7:4,purple,very thick] {(x-2)/(2*x+1)};
\draw[blue] (axis cs:-0.5,-6)--(axis cs:-0.5,6)
(axis cs:-4,0.5)--(axis cs:4,0.5);
\fill[red] (axis cs:-0.5,0.5) circle(1mm);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TrongVuong If you agree with this answer, then you accept it and vote for answer.

Answer (score 6):

A PSTricks answer for the PSTricks question.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\f{(x-2)/(2*x+1)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-4,-4)(6,5.5)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(5.5,5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red](-0.5,-4)(-0.5,5)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red](-4,0.5)(5,0.5)
    \psset{linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt}
    \psplot{-4}{-7 9 div}{\f}
    \psplot{-2 9 div}{5}{\f}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## NOTE

Increasing `plotpoints` sometimes is not a wise method because it will increase the size of its output (either PDF or SVG).

## More flexible solution

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\f(#1){((#1-2)/(2*(#1)+1))}% y=f(x)
\def\g(#1){((2+#1)/(1-2*(#1)))}% y=g(x) in which g is the inverse of f.

\pstVerb{/I2P {AlgParser cvx exec} def}% infix to postfix operator

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-4,-4)(6,6)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(5.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red](-0.5,-4)(-0.5,5)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red](-4,0.5)(5,0.5)
    \psset{linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt}
    \psplot{-4}{\g(5) I2P}{\f(x)}
    \psplot{\g(-4) I2P}{5}{\f(x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-6,-6)(6,6)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-5.5,-5.5)(5.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=0.2pt](-0.5,-5.5)(-0.5,5.5)
  \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=0.2pt](-5.5,0.5)(5.5,0.5)
  \psplot[plotpoints=1001,linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt,
      yMaxValue=5.25]{-5.5}{5}{(x-2)/(2*x+1)}
  \psdots[linecolor=red](-0.5,0.5)(0,0)(0,-2)(1,0)(2,0) 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]